# How do I prevent ReactJS onclick function from running on render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't want the function to be called when the page loads but only when the user actually clicks the row

Here are my basic snippets:

**JS**

```
function readDetails(id){
    console.log(id)
}
```

**JSX**

```
<tr key={data.id} onClick={() => { readDetails (data.id)} }>
```

Comment: Please don't change your question to include the answers as it invalidates them from the eyes of SO users.

Comment: Also, please include a [mcve]. There's not enough information in your question right now to really tell why without shooting in the dark.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use onClick in react.js?](//stackoverflow.com/q/51832797/90527)

Answer (score 0):

Method 1:

```
<tr key={data.id} onClick={() => readDetails(data.id)}>
```

Method 2:

```
const readDetails = (id) => {
  return () => {
    console.log(id)
  }
}

<tr key={data.id} onClick={readDetails(data.id)}>
```

Comment: I tried this but got the same behavior. It was running on render

Comment: Yeah method 2 will always fire the readDetails on render.

Comment: @DeanJames Actually, it won't. method 2 returns a function on render.

Comment: @CalebC.Adainoo, can you share the rest of the component code.

Comment: Oh yeah, I missed your curry func :)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by changing

```html
<tr key={data.id} onClick={readDetails (data.id)}>
```

To this:

```html
<tr key={data.id} onClick={() => { readDetails(data.id) }}>
```

You should also be able to remove the extra curly braces like this:

```html
<tr key={data.id} onClick={() => readDetails(data.id)}>
```

This will be supported on React 0.13.3 or above.

Answer (score 0):

After many trials I realized `calling a function within a table element doesn't really work well in ReactJS`. The best option to solve this issue was to use `divs` and style them to suit my `tabular pattern`.

Then I passed the function this way

```
<div key={data.id} onClick={() => readDetails(data.id)}>
    Table Data
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can solve this by changing

```
<tr key={data.id}  onClick={function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
this.readDetails(data.id);
.bind(this)}></tr>
```

Answer (score -1):

Considering you have a `key` prop in your example, I'm assuming you're looping over an array (or something similar) and outputting a collection of `<tr>` elements. Because of this, I'd recommend defining a function that you can just reference rather than defining a new function each loop for efficiency:

```
const readDetails = (e) => console.log(e.target.getAttribute('data-id'));
```

```
<tr key={data.id} data-id={data.id} onClick={readDetails}>
```

You have to define an extra prop however (in this case data-id) because the `key` prop is not available.